# Show that Brooks' theorem is equivalent to the following:

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness

If G is k-critical graph (k ≥ 4) which is not complete, then 
$\space\space 2\varepsilon ≥ \nu(k-1) + 1$
, where $\nu = |V(G)|, \varepsilon = |E(G)|$

***Brooks' theorem:** For any connected undirected graph G with maximum degree Δ, the chromatic number of G is at most Δ unless G is a complete graph or an odd cycle, in which case the chromatic number is Δ + 1.

Comment: what is $\epsilon$?

Comment: number of edges

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo Hey, you seem to be a brilliant graph theory solver, can't you solve this one? I have a final coming and really could use your help, I could even give you some bounty if you like.

Comment: I think you also need connectedness in the first theorem.

Comment: actually, nevermind that, critical graphs MUST always be connected anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proving Brook's theorem with the given result is easy.

All we have to do is show every non-complete connected graph $G$ which cannot be colored with $k+1$ colors must contain a vertex of degree at least $k+1$.

So let $G=G_1,\dots, G_m=H$ be a sequence of graphs obtained from the previous by removing non-cut vertices. It is easy to show that we eventually reach a $k$-critical graph, we stop at this point. So $H$ is a $k$-critical graph. If $H$ is complete then we are done, since at least one vertex must have been connected to one of the previously deleted vertices. So $G$ contains a vertex of at least $k+1$, if $H$ is not complete then notice that by the theorem $\frac{2\epsilon}{\nu}\geq k + \frac{1}{\nu}$ and so $\frac{2\epsilon}{\nu}>k$, since the average degree of $H$ is greater than $k$ it must contain a vertex of degree at least $k+1$.

---

We now prove the given result using Brooke's theorem.

We take a connected $k$-critical non-complete graph and prove that the sum of its degrees is at least $(k-1)\nu+1$.

It suffices to prove a vertex of degree at least $k$ exists and that every vertex has degree at least $k-1$.

The first part is clearly corollary of Brook's theorem. ( if every vertex had degree at most $k-1$ then the graph would be $k-1$-colorable by brook's theorem).

The second part is a consequence of the criticallity.

Take a vertex $v\in G$. Notice that $G\setminus v$ can be colored using $k-1$ colors, take one such coloring. If $v$ had degree less than $k-1$ then there would exist a color such that $v$ is not connected to any vertex of that color. And therefore $G$ would be $k-1$ colorable too.

We conclude every vertex has degree at least $k-1$ and at least one vertex had degree at least $k$. It follows $2\epsilon\geq \nu(k-1)+1$ as desired.